# Higher Order Function

Tags: function, higher-order-functions

I am having trouble understanding what my lecturer want me to do from this question. Can anyone help explain to me what he wants me to do?

Define a higher order version of the insertion sort algorithm. That is define
functions

```
insertBy :: Ord b => (a->b) -> a -> [a] -> [a] 

inssortBy :: Ord b => (a->b) -> [a] -> [a]
```

and this bit is where it got me confused: 
**such that inssort f l sorts the list l such that an element x comes before an elementyif f x < f y.**

Answer (score 1):

If you were sorting numbers, then it's clear what x < y means. But what if you were sorting letters? Or customers? Or anything else without a clear (to the computer) ordering?

So you are supposed to create a function f() that defines that ordering for the sorting procedure. That f() will take the letters or customers or whatever and will return an integer for each one that the computer can actually sort on.

At least, that's how the problem is described. I personally would have designed a predicate that accepted two items, x and y and returned a boolean if x < y. But whichever is fine.

Comment: Actually the description does not say anything about integers. In Haskell `(>)`can be used for any type that is ordered (expressed by the typeclass `Ord`). So the first parameter is just a function that turns `a`s into ordered `b`s.

Answer (score 0):

The code wants you to rewrite the insertion sort algorithm, but using a function as a parameter - thus a higher order function.

I would like to point out that this code, typo included, seems to stem from a piece of work currently due at a certain university - I found this page while searching for "insertion sort algortihm", as I copy pasted the term out of the document as well, typo included.

Seeking code from the internet is a risky business. Might I recommend the insertion sort algorithm wikipedia entry, or the Haskell code provided in your lecture slides (you are looking for the 'insertion sort algorithm' and for 'higher-order functions), as opposed to the several queries you have placed on Stack Overflow?